# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/LARAVEL/LaravelDesdeCero/laravel/resources/views/portfolio.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this problem while trying to print the portfolio items on screen.

My view looks like this:

```
<ul>
        @forelse ($portfolio as $portfolioItem)
            <li>{{ $portfolioItem->title }}</li>
        @empty
            <li>No hay proyectos para mostrar.</li>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
```

Controller code is like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class portfolioController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $portfolio = Project::get();

        return view('portfolio' , compact('portfolio'));
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: That means there is no title attribute in $portfolioItem, try to dump it first using  dd($portfolioItem) to check available elements

Comment: It throws this: array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #3"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #4"
  ]
]

Comment: Okay try $portfolioItem['title'] instead of $portfolioItem->title

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query returns an array, you need to use `[]` instead of the object accessor `->`.
You can check that via `dd($portfolio)`

Comment: It throw this: array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #3"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Proyecto #4"
  ]
]